# Get Empty Page when loading UI Form

Tags: magento2, grid, ui-form

I get a EmtyPage when loading UI Form, pls help me. Here is my code

[image]

DataProvider.php

```
<?php


namespace SimplifiedMagento\CustomAdmin\Model\Ui;


use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider;
use SimplifiedMagento\Database\Model\ResourceModel\AffiliateMember\CollectionFactory;

class DataProvider extends AbstractDataProvider
{
    protected $loadedData;
    public function __construct(
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = [])
    {
        $this->collection=$collectionFactory->create();
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    }

    public function getData()
    {
        if(isset($this->loadedData)) {
            return $this->loadedData;
        }
        $item=$this->collection->getItems();
        $this->loadedData=array();
        foreach ($item as $member) {
            $this->loadedData[$member->getId()]['member'] = $member->getData();
            var_dump($this->$member['name']);
        }
        return $this->loadedData;
    }

}
```

affiliate_member_form.xml

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">affiliate_member_form.affiliate_member_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">affiliate_member_form.affiliate_member_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Member Form</item>
        <item name="layout" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="type" xsi:type="string">tabs</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="affiliate_member_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">SimplifiedMagento\CustomAdmin\Model\Ui\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">affiliate_member_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
                <item name="submit_url" path="*/*/save" xsi:type="url"/>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>

    <fieldset name="member">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Member FieldSet</item>
            </item>
        </argument>

        <field name="entity_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">member</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Name</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">member</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="address">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Address</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">member</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="status">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">member</item>
                    <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
                    <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="true" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                        <item name="false" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="created_at">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Start Date</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">member</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">21</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd</item>
                        <item name="timeFormat" xsi:type="string">HH:mm:ss</item>
                        <item name="showsTime" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="updated_at">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Updated Date</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">member</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">21</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd</item>
                        <item name="timeFormat" xsi:type="string">HH:mm:ss</item>
                        <item name="showsTime" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="phone_number">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Phone Number</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">member</item>
                </item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="validate-digits" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Edit.php

```
<?php


namespace SimplifiedMagento\CustomAdmin\Controller\Adminhtml\Member;


use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use SimplifiedMagento\Database\Model\AffiliateMember;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class Edit extends Action
{
    protected $affiliateMember;
    protected $pageFactory;
    protected $registry;
    public function __construct(
        AffiliateMember $affiliateMember,
        PageFactory $pageFactory,
        Registry $registry,
        Action\Context $context)
    {
        $this->affiliateMember=$affiliateMember;
        $this->pageFactory=$pageFactory;
        $this->registry=$registry;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('SimplifiedMagento_CustomAdmin::parent');
    }
    /**
     * Execute action based on request and return result
     * Note: Request will be added as operation argument in future
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface\ResponseInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException
     */

    public function execute()
    {
        $id=$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $model=$this->affiliateMember;
        if($id) {
            $model->load($id);
            if(!$model->getId()) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage('Member does not exist');
                $result=$this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
                return $result->setPath('affiliate/member/index');
            }
        }
        $data=$this->_getSession()->getFormData(true);
        if(!empty($data)) {
            $model->setData($data);
        }
        $this->registry->register('member',$model);
        $resultPage=$this->pageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->addBreadcrumb($id ? __('Edit Member'): __('Add a New Member'));
        if($id) {
            $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend('Edit');
        }else {
            $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend('Add');
        }
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

file layout affiliate_member_edit.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="affiliate_member_form"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: add your error log here